# Is there a way to combine ggplots using ggpubr that preseves/does not squish the x-axis and y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to combine several graphs i made using ggplot in an rmarkdown document into one figure using ggpubr, but the x-axis keeps getting compressed/squished. Is there a way to keep the original scale of the graphs ( just make them smaller) so that the will sit side by side without compressing the x-axis?

I don't want the x-axis compressed like this:
[image: I don't want the x-axis compressed like this]

This is the original graph:
[image: This is the original graph]

I hope I have explained my problem clear enough! Thank you

I expected when i used ggpubr that three mini versions of the original graph would be displayed in a figure side by side. I have had trouble finding a solution

Comment: I have also tried the plot_grid function in cowplot. It does the same thing. I feel like I am missing something

Comment: The issue is that neither ggarrange or plot_grid or ... will shrink your plots. You have to take account of that yourself by reducing the font sizes, ...  And one option would indeed be to use facetting as outlined in the answer as it removes the duplicated y axis and labels and the tags and thereby creates more room for the x axis.

Comment: Can you provide any additional code and an example dataset that creates a plot with the shrinking you described?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data, you might be able to use [facet_wrap](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html) to facet by a variable, or you can use [cowplot](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/plot_grid.html) to plot three separate plots next to each other.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
data(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl, color = factor(gear))) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(~gear)
```

[image]

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = subset(mtcars, gear %in% 3), aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(color = "red")

p2 <- ggplot(data = subset(mtcars, gear %in% 4), aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(color = "blue") + ylab("")

p3 <- ggplot(data = subset(mtcars, gear %in% 5), aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(color = "green") + ylab("")

cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, nrow = 1)
```

[image]